# Getting equal or greater than number from the list of number in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array containing lists of numbers. I need to compare it to the variable and get the equal or slightly greater than the variable's value.

```
var items=[1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7];
var a=3.5;
```

Here, I want to compare `var a` with each item of `items` and assign `var b` with a value from `items` which is equal to or greater than th `var a`.
Note: I need only one value;in this case i need `3.7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7];
var a = 3.5;
var filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item >= a;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

*If you are expecting only one value*

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7];
var a = 3.5;
var filtered = items.filter(function(x, y) {
  return x >= a;
});
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, filtered)); //To get the minimum value from array

console.log(filtered.sort()); //To sort the filtered values
```

Answer (score 4):

Use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)** method to filter value from array and get minimum value from array using **[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** with **[`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7];
var a = 3.5;

console.log(
  // get min value from filtered array
  Math.min.apply(Math, items.filter(function(v) {
    return v >= a; // filter value greater than or equal
  }))
)
```

---

Or use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7];
var a = 3.5;

console.log(
  items.reduce(function(r, v) {
    // check value is greater than or equal and then return the min value
    return (v >= a && (r == undefined || v < r)) ? v : r;
  }, undefined)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A single loop with a [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) should help.

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3.4, 3.8, 4.8, 4.2, 2.3, 1.5, 3.7],
    a = 3.5,
    result = items.reduce(function (r, b) {
        return b > a && (r === undefined || b < r) ? b : r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```